# How to do the following with C?

Tags: c, loops

Basically I want to create an int `x`for every time a condition is met so something like...

```
while(CONDITION){
    if(int x = 100){
       //create a new int
       //refrence newly created variable
      }
   }
```

I then want to run through the loop again but testing newly created variable instead of x. Hopefully this is clear enough!

Comment: Your conditional expression is not what you think it is.

Comment: Ask for help to solve the problem, not the step.

Comment: You really should edit this question to make it more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of "creating an int" in **C language**. You can assign a new value to an existing `int` if you want:

```
int x, newx;
while(CONDITION){
   if(x == 100){
      newx = x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `C99` snippet below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int x;
    x = i * 2;
}
```

the `x` is a brand new `x` every time through the loop.
During the time the program runs that snippet, there will be 4 different `x`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but it sounds almost like you want a `for` loop. E.g.

```
for (int x = 100; CONDITION; /* do something to x here */) {
  /* use x */
}
```

This will start `x` at 100, and continue looping while `CONDITION` is true. Depending on what you replace `/* do something to x here */` with, the value of `x` within the loop will change each time. For a concrete example:

```
for (int x = 100; x < 200; x = x + 1) {
  printf("%d", x);
}
```

will print all numbers between 100 and 199 (inclusive). Note that `x = x + 1` can also be written `++x` or `x++`; I wrote it longhand for clarity, since you seem to be new to C.

The above assumes you have a C99 compiler. If your complier supports only C89, you will have to declare `x` at the beginning of the function and replace `int x = 100` with simply `x = 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't at all clear, but I think recursion may help you.

```
void do_it(void) {
    if (CONDITION) {
        int X = something_having_to_do_with_condtion(CONDITION); // the code you had
                                                     // for initializing X made no sense
        do_it(void); // recursive call

        process_x(X);
    }
}
```

You could do similar things with other dynamic allocation but the overhead is probably greater than that of recursion.